# AdMob not getting display on device ionic

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, admob

i am trying to display admob inside my application but it's not getting displayed on screen.

I added its plugins :- cordova plugin add com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.admob
cordova plugin add https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob.git

here is my code which i have done in my app.js class under run function :-

```js
$ionicPlatform
  .ready(function() {

      if (window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob) {
        alert('inside');
        var admob_key = device.platform == "Android" ? "ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/4748283957" : "IOS_PUBLISHER_KEY";
        var admob = window.plugins.AdMob;
        admob
          .createBannerView({
              'adId': admob_key,
              'position': admob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
              'adSize': admob.AD_SIZE.BANNER,
              'bannerAtTop': false
            },
            function() {
              admob
                .requestAd({
                    'isTesting': false
                  },
                  function() {
                    admob
                      .showAd(true);
                  },
                  function() {
                    alert("failed to request ad");
                    console
                      .log('failed to request ad');
                  });
            },
            function() {
              alert("failed to create banner view");
              console
                .log('failed to create banner view');
            });
      } else {
        alert("AdMob plugin not available/ready.");
      }
```

links from which i refer above code :-

1) https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/using-admob-ionicframework/

2) https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

Please provide me any suggestion on it.

Thanks

Comment: I've recently worked with admob and followed the blog made by nraboy. I think he uses an older version of admob because `bannerAtTop` is no longer a config option. If you actually inspect admob's JavaScript you'll notice it has changed to `position` so try something like `position: admob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER`

Comment: After checking my code I also noticed that the `publisherId` option is now `adId`, so try changing that to `adId: admob_key`

Comment: Hey  Will.Harris,thanks for your reply ..can you please provide me  one dummy sample, i have also updated the code as you mentioned

Comment: But still its not getting addmob plugin....it straight way displaying alert with message "AdMob plugin not available/ready" , means my else part is working

Comment: I was getting the exact same problem and after some testing I noticed Admob didn't exist under `window.plugins.Admob` instead it was just `window.Admob`, i'll add my code as an answer so you can see a dummy template

Comment: Thanks , that will be great help to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things have changed between the latest version of Admob and that in the blog by nraboy. I noticed the following differences a few weeks back when I used the plugin after I inspected the plugins .js file to figure out the changes:

- Admob was no longer located under `window.plugins.Admob` I found it under `window.Admob`
- Config option `publisherId` is now `adId`
- Config option `bannerAtTop`is now `position`
- `admob.createBannerView()` is now just `admob.createBanner()` which does all the work for you when it comes to showing the add (you don't need to call `admob.requestAd()`) etc.

**Template to follow**

```
           if (window.AdMob) {
                var admob = window.AdMob;
                admob.createBanner({
                    adId: admob_key,
                    adSize: admob.AD_SIZE.SMART_BANNER,
                    position: admob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
                    isTesting: false, //Live
                    //isTesting: true, //Test
                    autoShow: true
                }, function (data) {
                    console.log('Banner created... ' + angular.toJson(data));
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log('Failed to create banner view... ' + angular.toJson(err));
                });
            } else {
                //plugin not found
            }
```

**Additional Info**

In case you aren't aware of other AD_SIZE and AD_POSITION options (copied from the plugins .js file)

```
.AD_POSITION = {
  NO_CHANGE: 0,
  TOP_LEFT: 1,
  TOP_CENTER: 2,
  TOP_RIGHT: 3,
  LEFT: 4,
  CENTER: 5,
  RIGHT: 6,
  BOTTOM_LEFT: 7,
  BOTTOM_CENTER: 8,
  BOTTOM_RIGHT: 9,
  POS_XY: 10
};

.AD_SIZE = {
  SMART_BANNER: 'SMART_BANNER',
  BANNER: 'BANNER',
  MEDIUM_RECTANGLE: 'MEDIUM_RECTANGLE',
  FULL_BANNER: 'FULL_BANNER',
  LEADERBOARD: 'LEADERBOARD',
  SKYSCRAPER: 'SKYSCRAPER'
};
```

Comment: okay so here in place of adId: ids.banner my admob_key works ?

Comment: yes thats where your admob_key goes I will update the answer